# Align label of the ImageItem in J2ME Polish

Tags: java-me, label, alignment, j2mepolish

Is it possible to align the label of the ImageItem at the left of the image in J2ME Polish?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem using `IconCustomItem` instead of `ImageItem`.